# Brownian bridge's level reaching probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $X_{t}=\sigma\cdot B_{t}$ ($\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$) be a Brownian
bridge where $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian bridge with fixed endpoints:
$B_{T_{1}}=a$ and $B_{T_{2}}=b$ on the interval $[T_{1},T_{2}]$,
and $m$ is a real constant.

How can I proove

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in\left[T_{1},T_{2}\right]:\sup_{T_{1}\leq t\leq T_{2}}X_{t}>m\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{2\left(m-a\right)\left(m-b\right)}{\left(T_{2}-T_{1}\right)\sigma^{2}}\right)?
$$
I can proove $\mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in\left[0,1\right]:\sup_{0\leq t\leq1}B_{t}>a+(b-a)\cdot t;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right)=\exp\left(-2ab\right)$,
if $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian bridge with $0$ startpoint and
endpoint, but I couldn't deal with the asked problem.

Comment: The event $\{\exists t\in\left[T_{1},T_{2}\right]:\sup_{T_{1}\leq t\leq T_{2}}X_{t}>m\}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it? It means what is the probability that the Brownian bridge discussed above reach an appropriate $m$ level on interval $\left[T_{1},T_{2}\right]$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify things, I'll set $T_1=0$, $T_2=l$, and $\sigma=1$. Then the law of $\{X(t):0\le t\le l\}$ equals to that of
$$
\left\{a+(b-a)\frac{t}{l}+\frac{l-t}{l}W\!\left(\frac{lt}{l-t}\right):0\le t\le l\right\},
$$
where $\{W(t)\}$ is a standard BM. Thus, for $m\ge a\vee b$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\exists t\in[0,l]:X(t)> m)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{s\ge 0}\left(W(s)-\frac{m-b}{l}\cdot s\right)> (m-a)\right)=e^{-\frac{2(m-b)(m-a)}{l}}.
$$
(See, e.g., Eq. 1.1.4(1) on page 256 [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764367053).)